# $f_k$ differentiable$ \implies f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}f_k(x_k)$ is differentiable

Tags: calculus

Let $f_k:(a,b)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ differentiable functions by $1\leq k\leq n$. Let $f:(a,b)^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}f_k(x_k)$$ Prove that  $f$ is differentiable and calculate its derivative at any point of its domain

Comment: Can you write this as a composition of functions that are obviously continuous? Knowing that a function is continuous if and only if it's components are...

Comment: @EdvardFagerholm: No, that's not quite right. You need to observe that $(a,b)^n \overset{\pi_k}{\longrightarrow} (a,b)\overset{f_k}{\longrightarrow}\mathbb R$ is differentiable. Maybe I'm misinterpreting your use of the term "components."

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this quickly and used the wrong word. Continuous should be differentiable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the functions:

$$(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto \sum_{k=1}^n x_k$$

and

$$(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto x_k\mapsto f_k(x_k)$$

Use these to build your function through composition. Now apply the chain rule.